# Get An Avarage of Last 4 Columns in a Row in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need the calculate avarage of the last four non empty columns. The thing is column number is not fixed. Lets say the last value entered column is B4.
In the future some values might be added to other columns like B5, B6.

The thing is formule must calculate last 4 of them.

What i tried is getting index of last non empty column but didn't work properly.

Comment: You can use `COUNTA` to find number of used rows (Depending on your excel set up, this will likely be your last row.). You can then use this with combination of `OFFSET` to determine the range to average

Answer (score 0):

"Avarage of the last four non empty columns" - the last four cells in a column?

[image]

`=SUM(OFFSET(A1,COUNT(A:A)-1,0,-4,1))`